# Javascript: function is returning {} rather than an integer (which is what I expected), Promises issue?

Tags: javascript, return, es6-promise, console.log

I'm still relatively new with JavaScript (and programming in general) so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

I'm currently working on a mini project involving stock prices but am running into an issue which I'm having some trouble resolving.

I'm writing a function called getStockPrice which takes in a stock ticker name and returns the stock price (as an integer) by calling an API function from alphavantage.

```js
async function getStockPrice(ticker) {
  let num = 0;
  await alpha.data.quote(ticker).then((data) => {
    num = parseInt(data["Global Quote"]["05. price"]);
  });
  console.log(num);
  return num;
}
```

The console.log(num) line within the function prints out the stock price as I would've expected.

However, when I save the value from getStockPrice into a variable and insert said variable into my database, the database gets an empty object {} instead of the stock price which is what I wanted.

```js
const price = getStockPrice(ticker);
```

Could this somehow be related to the promises feature in JavaScript? Since logging the return value of getStockPrice gets me an integer, I'm surprised the function is outputting an empty object.

If someone could point me into the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Async functions always return a promise

Comment: What you actually end up is assigning a promise to `price` that waits yo be resolved

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#:~:text=Async%20functions%20always%20return%20a,implicitly%20wrapped%20in%20a%20promise.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work as async function returns a promise.

Please try the following code instead.

```
async function getStockPrice(ticker) {
  const data = await alpha.data.quote(ticker);
  const num = parseInt(data["Global Quote"]["05. price"]);
  console.log(num);
  return num;
}

(async () => {
 const price = await getStockPrice(ticker);
 console.log(price);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding
`await` before calling the function.

Comment: Could you explain why they need to add await ?It might be helpful for future readers

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked! My head was hurting trying to fix this.

Comment: The function is returning a promise , so either a .then block would be required to get the returned block or the await keyword, .then would be called once promise is resolved but await would force to wait until something is returned